# store the last part path of file in variable?

Tags: windows, unix, bash, command-line-interface

store the last part path of file in variable?

i have path for example :-
`$1=/path1/path2/path3`

i want to store `path3` in variable

`x=path3`

how i can do it in :-
1-windows
2-unix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use either [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) or the [basename](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/basename-invocation.html) utility.

```
x=${1##*/}

x=$(basename "$1")
```

Comment: Forgot the quotes, but otherwise yes.

Comment: Quotes are not necessary if the variable is the only thing coming from the assignment, i.e., `$` is right after `=`.

Comment: how i can make this in windows ???

Comment: @Osama Since your question is tagged 'bash', I guess it is about bash, no? Bash is the same in both Windows and Unix. If you want to know how to do this in cmd.exe, then that is another completely different thing.

Comment: @Osama install `cygwin` on Windows. Then you'll have a decent command interpreted along with most of the linux commands, including the `bash` interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows (shell script):

```
set FILE=c:\temp\test.txt
for /f %%F in ("%FILE%") do set FILE=%%~nF%%~xF
echo %FILE%
```

Comment: In the "How to Format" instructions to the right of the input box, it says "indent code by 4 spaces".